# Nodejs turn off http debugging info

Tags: node.js

I'm getting a bunch of debug info (without having set anything) like this:

```
GET /echo/info 0ms 200
POST /echo/152/8_4fl_ep/xhr?t=1382556167337 0ms (unfinished)
GET /echo/info 0ms 200
POST /echo/876/st9gz4bi/xhr?t=1382556172720 0ms (unfinished)
GET /echo/info 0ms 200
GET /echo/info 0ms 200
```

I've identified that the line that causes this is the following:

```
var my_http = require("http");
var sockjs  = require('sockjs');

....
var server = my_http.createServer();
echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/echo'}); // <---- This line causes it
server.listen(8081, '0.0.0.0');
```

Seems to be something in the `var my_http = require("http");`

Any ideas how to turn this off? My log get completely spammed with those request infos

This is `echo`

```
var echo = sockjs.createServer();
echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
    conn.on('data', function(message) {});
    conn.on('close', function() {});
});
```

Comment: What is `echo`? And what is `installHandlers`?

Comment: `installhandlers` is for `sockjs` https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's actually coming from sockjs. From their [documentation](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node), you can override their logging with your own function (and possibly use severity to log only warnings/errors):

```
var echo = sockjs.createServer({
    log: function (severity, message) {
        // Place your logging here if desired
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `var echo = sockjs.createServer({log: function () {}});`

From the docs:

> log (function(severity, message))
>   It's quite useful, especially for debugging, to see some messages printed by a SockJS-node library. This is done using this `log` function, which is by default set to `console.log`. If this behaviour annoys you for some reason, override `log` setting with a custom handler. The following `severities` are used: `debug` (miscellaneous logs), `info` (requests logs), `error` (serious errors, consider filing an issue).

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/echo'});
```

to:

```
echo.installHandlers(server, {
  log: function () {},
  prefix:'/echo'
});
```

Then logging should be gone. If you want to redirect logging to somewhere else but the console, you may use it as follows:

```
echo.installHandlers(server, {
  log: function (severity, message) {
    // Do whatever you want to do here…
  },
  prefix:'/echo'
});
```

`message` is self-explaining, `severity` may be one of `debug`, `info` and `error`. For details see the [SockJS documentation](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node#server-class). Although `log` is basically an option for a SockJS server, you can override it in your call to `installHandlers`.